# Missing Tag for 'speech-synthesis'

Tags: support, status-completed

I am reputational-challenged (because I am a newbie to the site I hasten to add) - and am therefore deemed unworthy to add a tag 'speech-synthesis' at this point.

If it seems reasonable to do this - can somebody add it ? (I logged a couple of posts today on the topic today : but had to use just 'audio').

Comment: I have created the tag, and applied it to this [questions][1].


  [1]: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/28172/56

Comment: +1 for reputational-challenged

Comment: Thanks - and the +1 is appreciated as well !